# How to check for Enter key press inside the case statement in linux shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am automating a task through shell script, in which I have a menu to select a choice.
Here is the code portion for that option menu.

```
OPTIONS="FULL SPLIT"
PS3="ENTER THE CHOICE:"
select opt in $OPTIONS
  do
     case $opt in
       FULL)
         OPTION=1
         break
         ;;
       SPLIT)
         OPTION=2
         break
         ;;
       "")
         echo "Option not selected continue with default FULL method"
         break
         ;;
       *)
         OPTION=1
         echo "no option selected"
         break
    esac 
done
```

My requirement is if the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key the OPTION variable must be set to value 1. I have tried to check the enter key using "") but it doesn't work.
Could any one please help to validate the enter key press in the `case` statement?

Comment: Why not use `read` and get a value and do the check instead of detecting keyboard keys?

Comment: I am trying to learn "select" in shell script.

Comment: BTW, it is already set to `1` when you choose `FULL`

Comment: Yes, But my requirement is if I press enter without giving a valid choice I need to set the OPTION value to 1

Comment: But you cannot read a user input from command line without `read`, it is just not possible

Comment: As Inian said, youare looking for user input in bash, you start with "read".  How you compare that input in your case/select statement it really a separate problem.

Comment: `select` will not return until the user types a non-empty line. If you want to be able to detect empty lines, you cannot use `select`.

Comment: 0 seems to be the ASCII code for ENTER key. Try: case $(printf %d\\n \'$option) in 0) echo "Enter was hit" ;; esac.